# postman how to show Time of execution in newman Command

Tags: postman, postman-collection-runner, newman

I am using NewMan Command for PostMan to execute request periodically as the following :

```
newman run TestHitinProd.postman_collection.json   -n 10000 --delay-request 300000  --verbose
```

I want to show the time of execution but above doesn't show even with using --verbose .
My question, how to show the Time of execution through command line `NewMan run`
Thanks

Comment: Do you mean the total amount of time the test run took to complete or the point in time that the test run started?

Comment: Martin H. , Not the total amount  , I meant the time for each iteration , thx

Comment: You could add 2 variables to your collection vars, one holding a time stamp from when the iteration starts and one that gets added on your last request in the collection. Then you can calculate the time it took for the iteration to finish and output that trough `console.log()`, it should end up in your CLI.